# how can i get the number of males and females from the file?

Tags: python

> The Q is **Assignment**
> Use the attached archived web page from the MOH contact tracing data to collect using regular
> expressions a dataset. Sample html page found here:
> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fK-4wA4jW69fbjxuP5WopSoKzYdy2oGs/view?usp=sharing
> Use the regular expressions library in Python to read the data about the cases, extracting
> information on:
> • Case No
> • Age
> • Nationality
> • Sex
> • Travel History
> • Contact Tracing
> Task1. Read this information into a suitable data structure in Python (you choose) then store
> this information in an open format file (text, JSON, etc.). Label the file with the date the
> webpage was last updated.
> Task 2. Determine the number of males and females in the cases, average age, and print them
> out on the screen.

and my code for now is

```
import re

# open and read the file after the appending:
userinfo = open("usersinfo.txt", "r")

# Creating userinfo
# userinfo.write("1.\t18 \tBahraini\tF\tUS,AL\t\tParent\n")
# userinfo.write("2.\t29 \tJapanese\tM\tBH,CH\t\tWife\n")
# userinfo.write("3.\t55 \tJapanese\tM\tBH\t\tSon\n")
# userinfo.write("4.\t21 \tBahraini\tF\tKW,CH\t\tParent\n")
# userinfo.write("5.\t24 \tBahraini\tF\tDK\t\tHusband\n")
# userinfo.write("6.\t30 \tEgyptian\tM\tDK\t\tParent\n")
# userinfo.write("7.\t23 \tEgyptian\tM\tDK\t\tParent\n")
# userinfo.write("8.\t32 \tEgyptian\tM\tFR\t\tWife\n")
# userinfo.write("9.\t29 \tIndian\tF\tKW,RO\t\tBrother\n")
# userinfo.write("10.\t21 \tIndian\tM\tRS\t\tParent\n")

countMale = 0
countFemale = 0
# Q1
for x in userinfo:
    re_gender = re.findall("[M|F]\b", userinfo.read())
    if re_gender == 'M':
        countMale += 1
    else:
        countFemale += 1
    print("The number of males: ", countMale, ", females: ", countFemale)

# Q2
for x in userinfo:
    ages = re.findall("\d{2}\s", userinfo.read())
    avg_age = sum(int(age) for age in ages) / len(ages)
    print("The average age: ", avg_age)

print(userinfo.read())
userinfo.close()
```

Comment: Why iterate over `userinfo` *and* use `userinfo.read()`?

Comment: i dont know tbh, i didnt study python, i converted all my knowledge from java to python, im asking why is it wrong?

Comment: It's unclear what you are expecting vs. what you are getting with the above code. Can you clarify how the output is different from what you are expecting?

Comment: sorry for that, i fixed it already, but have some issue with task 1, need to know how can i do it with python ^^"

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an assignment, I won't solve the problem but I will give some pointers to get you moving in the right direction.

First, your file is a tab-delimited file. I'd recommend taking a look at the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module for how to read these sorts of files directly. This will probably help you simplify your code dramatically.

Second, there is a difference between iterating over a file handle and using `file.read().` `for line in file:` will produce the lines one at a time, whereas `file.read()` *exhausts* the file handle. Looking at your first loop:

```py
for x in userinfo: # produces the first line
    content = userinfo.read() # exhausts the handle
```

This means that your for loop will stop immediately. If you want to search each line, then search the line itself:

```py
for x in userinfo:
    do_something(x)
```

I'd look up the basics on how to use files in python.

Another potential pitfall: iterating over a file twice. Iterating also exhausts the handle. If you want to do that more than once, you'll need to `seek` to the beginning:

```py
fh = open('somefile.txt')

for line in fh:
    continue

for line in fh:
    print("line!") # won't print anything
```

I need to do the following

```py
fh = open('somefile.txt')

for line in fh:
    continue

# add this
fh.seek(0)

for line in fh:
    print("line!") # now I can iterate again
```

Comment: worked, the details was helpful, thank you.